# Angular: event unbinding in directive somehow does not unbind entirely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling

We have a directive that shows a popup,
in the popup a template is loaded, with a directive that catches all clicks in the document.

when that happens it broadcasts an event to close the popup, and unbind the event on the `$document`.

this is the directive that catches the document clicks.

```
aOS.directive('catchOutsideClick',
    [
        '$document',
        'eventsService',
        function CatchOutsideClickDirective($document, eventsService) {

            var CatchClick = function CatchClick(scope, element, attrs) {

                // Check if there was clicked on parent or one of its children
                function isDescendant(parent, child) {
                    var node = child.parentNode;
                    while (node !== null) {
                        if (node === parent) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        node = node.parentNode;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                // Done clicking
                var onOutsideClick = function onOutsideClick(event) {
                    var clickedItem = event.target;
                    if (!isDescendant(element[0], clickedItem) && element[0] !== clickedItem) {
                        eventsService.publish('clicked-outside-popup', element[0]);
                        $document.unbind('click', onOutsideClick);
                    }
                };

                // Catch clicks!
                $document.bind('click', onOutsideClick);
            };

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: false,
                link: CatchClick
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

this is the html that loads the popup:

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="framework.header">
    <div data-ng-include="popupTemplate"></div>
</div>
```

for the sake of simplicity, lets state that the controller `framework.header`
toggles the `$scope.popupTemplate` to a path of the html presented below:

```
<div ng-controller="user.profle" catch-outside-click>
    <!-- loads of content -->
</div>
```

the including of the template seems to work perfectly, however this is the behaviour we see now:

1. you click on the button that toggles the `popupTemplate` and it loads it into the popup div.
2. that fires the catch-outside-click directive nicely and binds a clickhandler on the document
3. a click inside the popup does nothing (as that is tested for in the directive), but a click outside the popup nicely closes the popup thanks to it broadcasting the event which is caught in the header controller.
4. clicking anywhere in the page does not trigger the directive again, so we believe it is correctly unbound.
5. except for when you click on the button to open the popup again. That seems to both bind a new document click event, but immediately triggers the clickhandler as well (this makes me think it triggers the first clickhandler).

I have no idea at this moment how to test whether it is triggering the first or the second clickhandler.

anyone got an idea how I can narrow this down, either I'm doing something entirely wrong, or just point me how I can debug this issue to see which eventhandler is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to fix this for now by doing this:

```
aOS.directive('catchOutsideClick',
[
    '$document',
    'eventsService',
    function CatchOutsideClickDirective($document, eventsService) {

        ...

        setTimeout( function() {
            $document.bind('click', onOutsideClick);
        }, 0);

        ...

    }
]);
```

It looks as if the code inside the setTimeout (binding to the click) gets executed in a next 'cycle' (although timeout is set to 0), where the click to include the template is handled in the same (previous) cycle as where the catch-click directive gets initialized. At least that's the feeling I get when investigating this problem.

If anyone can confirm this or has a more plausible explanation (and maybe a more logical solution), we're still eager to learn :-)

Comment: i think you're not taking event bubbling into account, as you're binding to clicks on document INSIDE the click handler for a descendant element? you'd just have to call event.stopPropagation() inside the buttons click handler